# Optimise SVG blur effect via downsampling

Tags: animation, svg, blur

I have an animated SVG image with a blur effect. The blur is added to the outermost group, and I'm using the standard filter:

```
<filter id="blur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" />
</filter>
```

Obviously, for an animated full-window image in a browser this is expensive. Safari/Chrome/Firefox use 100-150% CPU on my machine, and the page isn't very responsive, which is unacceptable.

If I was working with canvas or another technology, I would consider rendering the image at a lower resolution to make it much cheaper to animate. It's a background image so the appearance would be ok. Is there a way to do that with SVG? Or is there some other filter that is much cheaper than `feGaussianBlur`?

Edit: after some more reading, I found the [`filterRes`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterElementFilterResAttribute) filter option, which is exactly what I wanted, but doesn't seem to be supported by Chrome.

Comment: At least on Chrome, the -webkit-filter CSS path is faster for some types of filters because they do this on the GPU. GaussianBlur is the cheapest blur available in SVG filters - ConvolveMatrix is much slower.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox now follow the newer [Filter Effects Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/) which no longer supports filterRes

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, that does look like the reason filterRes only works in Safari — it's on the way out. CSS filtering is equally expensive in my testing. Filtering on individual elements seems cheaper than filtering the whole image, but leaves some nasty artefacts in Firefox for my image. Chrome doesn't like filters on certain groups. It's all a bit of a mess, compatibility-wise.

Comment: Raise a Firefox bug about the artifacts on [bugzilla](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org) with a testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way of doing this which is cross browser compatible. As @RobertLongson mentions, the promising looking `filterRes` attribute is no longer part of the spec.

I found blur via CSS filter to give no significant performance improvement across browsers compared to the SVG blur filter.

I plan either to do without blur (50-60% CPU on modern machines rather than closer to 100% with blur) or to rework the animation using Canvas (preferable as even using 50% CPU for a website sucks).

There's simply a big penalty to using the clean declarative mechanisms of SVG and CSS animations rather than writing drawing routines out manually for Canvas. Such is life!